# How can i echo string + command in terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

how can i 'echo' this command(NUMBER lines in my script):

```
Number of lines is 23.
```

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
.
.
.
.
echo Number of line is cat $0 | wc -l
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "This script is `wc -l $0 | cut -d " " -f 1` lines long."
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo "Number of line is `wc -l < $0`"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an another solution

```
 grep -c ^  [FILENAME]
```